# Selling my own second hand product that I bought off Amazon, using original Amazon images (UK)

Tags: copyright, commerce

I had bought a giant bean bag from Amazon that I would like to sell on [Gumtree](http://gumtree.com). Am I allowed to use the original images downloaded from Amazon, for my ad on Gumtree, in the UK? It feels illegal because I'm using someone else's images for my own financial gain, but I'd just like to clarify. In any case, I'm selling it for like £10, are they really going to press charges? If they do, how much fine would I have to pay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your feeling is correct. Copyright in those images is owned by Amazon, or by someone Amazon contracted with, in any case not by you. Using them to sell your bean bag would be infringement, unless you have been granted permission to use the images. (It is not very likely that you would be sued over this, but please do the right thing anyway.) In any case those stock images may not show quite how your particular bean-bag looks now. Take your own photo and upload it with your sale listing.